# A sharp increase eden space memory and server fault

Tags: memory, jvm, wildfly, wildfly-10, metaspace

[image]
My server is Wildfly.10.1.0.final.
I discovery sharp inscrease of "committed" eden space memory. Is there anyone explain some case committed eden space increase? Committed survivor memory decrease by committed eden space increase is problem too.

Strangely, Finally I always faced on "out of memory : metaspace". 
here is my java options and metaspace memory graph.
[image]
[image]

ps. 오전11:00 = AM11:00

Comment: Do you have any test case to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Use `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` and analyze the dump to see if anything is leaking. If there's no leak bump your memory limits.

Comment: @Fairoz no i have not .

Comment: @the8472 So i increase -XX:metaspaceSize:256 -> 512, and it seems to fine.. I will use heap dump on OOME. thx